# PHP form to insert into database, check for nothing entered

Tags: php, required

My question is, how do I get the form to display an error when the user doesn't input a field into the form. I can get it to work when they don't fill out the form at all and just hit enter, but cannot get it to work if they only fill out a few fields. They could fill out the title field and the run time field and will be able to submit it. How can I get it to make sure that every field is filled out?

```html
<?php
$databaseName = 'movie_database';
$databaseUser = 'root';
$databasePassword = 'root';
$databaseHost = '127.0.0.1';

$conn = new mysqli($databaseHost, $databaseUser, $databasePassword, $databaseName);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Connected successfully";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['title']);
$value2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['rating']);
$value3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(int)$_POST['Runtime']);
$value4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(float)$_POST['movie_rating']);
$value5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['release_date']);
// Checks for empty fields 
if (empty($value) && empty($value2) && empty($value3) && empty($value4) && empty($value5)) {
    echo 'Please correct the fields';
    return false;
}
// Concatenate the $values into the string
$sql = "INSERT INTO movies(title,rating,Runtime,movie_rating,release_date) 
 VALUES('$value','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5')";

if ($conn->query($sql)) {
    $msg = "New record created successfully";
} else {
    $msg = "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
?>
<form method="post"/>
<p>Enter Movie Title: <input type="text" name="title"/></p> 
<p>Enter Movie Rating(G,PG,PG-13,R): <input type="text" name="rating"/></p> 
<p>Enter Movie Runtime in minutes: <input type="text" name="Runtime"/></p> 
<p>Enter IMDB Movie Rating(0-10.0): <input type="text" name="movie_rating"/></p> 
<p>Enter Movie Release date(YYYY-MM-DD): <input type="text" name="release_date"/></p>  
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button
</form> 

<?php 
if (isset($msg)) {
 echo $msg;
}
?>
```

Comment: try using required attribute in the frontend, it will throw error automatically

Comment: e.g: empty($_POST['title']) // returns true if no content

Comment: Use `emtpy` on all fields that are expected... consult manual though if `0` or other specific values are expected..

Comment: you're using the && operator to test all fields at once. this will return true if just one field has a value. Use the || operator instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Front side you can add `required` attribute to each input. So add it in every input field like  : 
`<input type="text" name="title" required/>`

From back-end side (using PHP) If you want all value must be fill up then change `&&` with `||` in your condition

```
// Checks for empty fields 
if (empty($value) || empty($value2) || empty($value3) || empty($value4) || empty($value5)) {
    echo 'Please correct the fields';
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($value) && empty($value2) && empty($value3) && empty($value4) && empty($value5)) {
    echo 'Please correct the fields';
    return false;
}
```

This should be 'or'